# Change value of TextView from fragment function

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I have a fragment called `SpeedometerFragment` which has a respective XML layout `fragment_speedometer`

I have then created an independent layout called `fragment_distance`. There is no activity associated with this XML file.

I want to change the value of a textview "distanceText" in the `fragment_distance` XML file from a function call in `SpeedometerFragment`.

The `fragment_distance` is passed to a frameLayout inside my main activity.

I have tried the following inside onCreateView of `SpeedometerFragment` but there is no change to the textview:

**speedometerFragment**

```
       LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.fragment_distance, container, false);
        TextView dis = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distanceText);
        dis.setText("Test");
```

Comment: How is fragment_distance is passed to a frameLayout inside your main activity? Please provide some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I was complicating it in my original question, so there is no need to inflate anything and there is no need for the seperate `fragment_distance` XML file

I created a `public static TextView distance`  in my main activity.

Then in my fragment, when the value of distance changes, I use `Eye_Tracking_Main.distance.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(distance) + " Km");` to set the value of the TextView

In my main activity , I simply used `distance=findViewById(R.id.distancemain);`